# Scrolling sections scroll randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, slide, onepage-scroll

I need to code a website with onepage scroll sections without using a plugin(like [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)). So i just created 6 sections like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="hlpjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>My Website</title>
<link href="hlpcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <section id="section1">
        <h1>text1</h1>
    </section>
    <section id="section2">
        <h1>text2</h1>
    </section>
    <section id="section3">
        <h1>text3</h1>  
    </section>
    <section id="section4">
        <h1>text4</h1>  
    </section>
    <section id="section5">
        <h1>text5</h1>  
    </section>
    <section id="section6">
        <h1>text6</h1>  
    </section>
</body>
```

and i tried to scroll through the sections in a javascript document like this:

```js
var count = 1;
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
        if (count < 6) {
            count++;
            $('html, body').animate({

                    scrollTop: $("#section"+count).offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
    } else {
        if(count>1){
            count--;
            $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#section"+count).offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
});
```

But its not working as it should. It's just scrolling randomly until it's at the top(or bottom) and then it stops.

Comment: Probably because you are firing many animations on top of each other. Try using a 'flag' to only allow animations when no animation is happening at the moment. You can do this by using a `complete` callback on $.animate. Docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/. Also, your counters don't really make sense.

Comment: Am not sure what you are trying to achieve but here's fiddle just trying to debug your code  https://jsfiddle.net/46d0Lnfo/3/   This might give you clarity. Your count logic is not correct

Comment: @caulitomaz I want to scroll either one section down or one section up, so I use count for accessing the correct id of the previous or next section. What's wrong with that?

Comment: If you are trying to learn, go for it. Otherwise using a library will save you tens of hours of development.

Comment: @Alvaro I would like to use a library but this is part of a school project and we're not allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the if statements and added the complete callback so **now it works.** My only problem is now that I can scroll infinitely up and down but if i try to add any if statement the animations do not work at all(**Any suggestions?**). Otherwise i'm gonna go with that:

```js
var count = 1;
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
  count--;
        $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#section"+count).offset().top
                }, 1000,function(){
        $('html, body').clearQueue();
    });
    }
    else {
  count++;
        $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#section"+count).offset().top
                }, 1000,function(){
        $('html, body').clearQueue();
    });
 }
});
```